# Is there a way to change the contents of elements when they are selected?

Tags: javascript, dom, clipboard

Is it possible to change the contents of elements when they, or a part of the text within them, is selected then reverting them back when they are deselected?

The aim being that when they are copied to the clipboard the alternate value is copied.

The html looking something like this:

```
<p>Today is the <span class="date" value="18/03/2009">18th of March</span>.</p>
```

Comment: what do you mean by selected?

Comment: A user positions the mouse to the left of "Today" then presses the left mouse button down dragging the mouse over to the end of "March". At this point it is selected although there are other ways to select things like double or triple clicking a word.

Comment: Why do you want to change the text they copy?  Sounds like an interface design problem.

Comment: Sounds to me like Annan wants to show users something in a text box but not allow them to copy it for their own records... If they really want it, its not too hard to open textedit [notepad, vi, etc] and copy it down.

Comment: @Parchik, Or just copy manually.  =]  @Annan, If that is the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455623

Comment: It's for a greasemonkey script, when any page is loaded the html is parsed and certain strings are formatted. When the text is copied it needs to revert back to what it was before it was formatted.

Comment: Ah, makes much more sense that way, I was just guessing.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to be as generic as possible but in case anyone is interested in specifics its for http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/44478 . It converts decimals into sexagesimal, this can cause problems with things like plain text urls and phone numbers hence the need to copy the exact source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that I came up with is as follows.

HTML:

```
<p>Semper mi vitae tellus <span class="date" title="19/03/09" data="19th of March">19th of March</span> quis, augue.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.date {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This stops the text from jumping around when the content is replaced.

Javascript:

```
var travel = function(node, noChildren){
    if (node.firstChild && !noChildren) {
        return node.firstChild;
    }
    if (node.nextSibling) {
        return node.nextSibling;
    }
    return travel(node.parentNode, true);
};

var onMouseDown = function(event){
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName(revertClass);
    var i = spans.length;
    while (i) {
        i--;
        spans[i].innerHTML = spans[i].getAttribute('data');
        spans[i].className = window.baseClass;
    }

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount && event.button === 2){
        var n = selection.rangeCount;
        var k = n;
        do {
            var i = k-n;
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(i);

            var element = range.startContainer;
            var endContainer = range.endContainer;
            do {
                if (element.className === window.baseClass){
                    element.style.width = element.offsetWidth;
                    element.innerHTML = element.title;
                    element.className += ' ' + window.revertClass;
                }
                if (element == endContainer){
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (element = travel(element));

            var newRange = document.createRange();
            newRange.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            newRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);

            selection.removeRange(range);
            selection.addRange(newRange);
        }
        while (--n);
    }
};

var onKeyDown = function(event){
    //Ctrl + C
    if (event.keyCode === 67 && event.ctrlKey){
        event.button = 2;
        onMouseDown(event);
    }
    //Tab to deselect
    else if (event.keyCode === 9){
        onMouseDown(event);
    }
};

window.baseClass = 'date';
window.revertClass = 'date_revert';
window.addEventListener ('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener ('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
```

I purposely didn't use jquery as I'm planning on using this in a greasemonkey script and loading it on every page would slow things down (I think?). I had it working with it automatically changing on selection by binding mousemove after mousedown fired but it ended up being very slow so I decided it was best to focus on my goal of changing what was copied.

About the usage of non standard attributes, I've never found this to be a problem? I'm using title so that people can see the alternative format without copying it and data because it seemed logical.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: using hover instead (per Scott E. comment)

I like JQUERY and below is a way, albeit not perfect, but should get you started down the path. The reason that its not perfect is because there is a "fluttering" if you mouseover and out on the right side (interestingly) of the span.

Note this is fully functional, but you should get local version of the JQUERY js. Also,
after posting this the first time, I discovered I/E does not behave as expected.

See http://docs.jquery.com/Events and http://docs.jquery.com/Core

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Today is the <span class="date"/></p>
  </body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    // use data object of <span> element with class 'date'.
    // Do this instead of using "value" attribute in <span>
    // which is not normal part of <span> element
    // instead of putting the value directly in <span> above, I'm assigning it here

    $(".date").data("mydates", { selected : "18/03/2009", normal: "18th of March" } );

    // assign the normal value on startup
    $(".date").html($(".date").data("mydates").normal);

    // first function is executed on mouseover
    // second function is executed on mouseout
    $(".date").hover(
        function() {
            $(".date").html($(".date").data("mydates").selected);
        },
        function() {
            $(".date").html($(".date").data("mydates").normal);
        }
    );

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Just an FYI- the double bind of mouseenter and mouseleave is more easily handled by jquery's hover() function

Comment: Thanks Scott, other thing I found out was that this is flunky on IE.

Comment: Interesting solution, I'm just about to post my solution that I came up with. On problem with your answer is that if you select the date with other text and copy it you end up copying the 'normal' date. It's a good way to allow people to view an alternate format but a title may be better for that.